# Making a Value Equal a Average value

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I have two tables, one named `scores` and one named `dem0n123`.

I am trying to take the AVG of all of the `kills` in the section of the `demon123` table and insert that value into the `AverageKills` section of `scores` but only where the `Player` section of `scores` equals `dem0n123`.

I have tried a multitude of different ways and have yet to find anything that works.

*** edit ***

Better explanation, there are two tables:
-scores
-dem0n123

inside scores there are individual players and there average scores (Average Kills/Deaths/Assists... etc)

inside dem0n123 there are game scores (kills/deaths/assists... etc)

so taking from the dem0n123 table, I need the average of all his kills and then insert that value into the scores table "AverageKills" value

hope that is a better explanation

Comment: Post what you're tried and explain how it's not working.  Also, post the columns in your tables.

Comment: `demon123` or `dem0n123`?

Comment: What do you mean by `only where the Player section of scores equals dem0n123`? `dem0n123` is a table, how can a `Player` equal a whole table?

Comment: Better describe all with your query code, lasr where section is confusing as Barmar says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm guessing what you mean correctly, I think you want this:

```
UPDATE scores AS s
JOIN (SELECT Player, AVG(kills) AS avkills
      FROM dem0n123
      GROUP BY Player) AS d
ON s.Player = d.Player
SET s.AverageKills = d.avkills
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b5cb/1)

Comment: I am not exactly sure how this works?... what do the s and d mean? and what is avkills? is it supposed to be my "AverageKills" or something completely different.. and "Player" and "Kills" are in seperate tables, will this affect anything?

Comment: where it says `AVG(kills) avkills` you're aliasing the field AVG(kills) to the name avkills. where it says `update scores s`, you're aliasing the scores table to s. Then `join (select......) d` you're aliasing the whole join to d. Try to think about it, its actually a fairly simple query. Now after you run this query, you'll need to run another query to insert records where they don't exist in your table.

Comment: @user3014598 I've added the `AS` keywords, maybe that will make it more recognizable to you. In MySQL these keywords are optional and I don't usually use them, although I probably should be more verbose in SO answers. Other than that, this is basic, beginner SQL syntax.

Comment: You say _Player and Kills are in searate tables_. Isn't `Player` in both tables?

Comment: Player is not in both tables, I suppose I could add that... but ATM there is a seperate table for each player and inside dem0n123 it is just scores, no Player column

Comment: I just tested this, it works wonderfully, better then I expected actually, cause its able to update all my players at once! Thank you very much for this answer

Comment: If the player isn't in the dem0n123 table, how do you know who the kills were done by, and how can you calculate the average number of kills for the player?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform a function on the column. The function you would like is AVG. For example

```
Select AVG(kills) from scores
```

Then after that you will want to insert into your other table.

```
insert into dem0n123(average) 
    select AVG(kills) from scores
```

Comment: This works, sort of... The only problem is it makes a brand new row, instead of inserting it where Player='dem0n123'